# Not able to select subscription ID in azure

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am using below code to select subscription id in Power shell script, but when i click on the subscription id it does not select...

$subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Azure Subscription:' -PassThru).SubscriptionId Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this script to do it:

```
$subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Azure Subscription:' -PassThru).Id 
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

We should use `Id`, not `SubscriptionId`, we can find the output here:

```
PS C:\Users\v-jianye> Get-AzureRmSubscription

Name     : Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN
Id       : 5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx
TenantId : 1fcfxxxx-xxx-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8xxxx
State    : Enabled
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, the script when runs, it gives options to select the subscription id to user from multiple subscriptions, so now i will use $subid = ... ? am i correct?

Comment: No, in your script, `$subscriptionId` contain `name`, `Id`, 'TenantId' and `state`, `Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId` need the ID, so we can use `$subscriptionId.Id`, or use `$subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Azure Subscription:' -PassThru).Id` in this way, we can get the subscription Id to $subscriptionId.